# Tooltip not shown in swt

Tags: java, swt, tooltip, jface

I am trying to set tooltip for items in a TreeViewer in swt.

```
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer);

DocumentTreeLabelProvider labelProvider = new DocumentTreeLabelProvider();
viewer.setLabelProvider(new DecoratingLabelProvider(labelProvider, labelProvider));
```

The labelProvider class looks like this:

```
public class DocumentTreeLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider implements ILabelDecorator {
    ...

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(Object element) {
        return "tooltip"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that tooltips are never displayed and I have no idea why ??

Answer (score 1):

`ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` only looks at the main label provider for the column (`DecoratingLabelProvider` in your case).

You will have to use a label provider which supports tool tips for the main label provider, `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider` for example. Extend that label provider to add the `getToolTipText` method.

Comment: I am new to this. The problem is that if I use a LabelProvider instead of DecoratingLabelProvider, I cannot decorate the icons anymore.

Comment: I said use something like `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider` which does decorate.

Comment: For some reason `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider` does not exist in my classpath..

Comment: It is in the some plugin / package as ColumnLabelProvider unless you are using a very, very old JFace.

Comment: ok. seems that my project is using an older version of JFace. Is there any workaround this without `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider` ? Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea as I have not used such a very old version of JFace for a long time and I don't know what it supported.

Comment: @adi.neag Are you sure you are using such an old jface, time to upgrade! DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider has been around since 2008 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=219393 and http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/log/bundles/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java